# Retrieving data from database as a list

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am working on c# program with access database that contains criteria ,

I know how to retrieve all criteria from database to `datagridview`

```
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connect;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT Criteria FROM ERPs";

        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

            dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells["Criteria"].Value = reader[0].ToString();  

        }
```

But i want  to retrieve all criteria from the  database as a list and let  the user to choose some criteria

then show the selected criteria in the `datagridview`.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: I don't get it. Do you have a problem creating List? Or binding that list to Listcontrol or Datagrid or using Multiselect?

Comment: creating List , and the user select from that list , the items that user select from that list appear in datagridview

Answer (score 0):

try retrieving the criteria in a component on page_load event (i guess a multicolumncombobox or a simple combobox would be great) and then use another SQL function to show the selected criteria in the datagridview after the user will pick his desired criteria on the selectionchanged event

It will go something like this:

This is on the page_load event:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Criteria FROM ERPs"
'the display member will be the criteria and the value will be the id
```

This is on SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT Criteria FROM ERPs WHERE ID=" & ComboBox1.selectedvalue & "
```

Hope it will help.